# A special infinity server queue

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, queueing-theory

I have a question about setting up the generator matrix of the problem below.

Suppose customers arrive to a processing center in accordance to a Poisson process with rate λ. This center consists of infinitely many servers, labeled $1, 2, 3, . . .$. An arriving customer always joins the lowest-numbered available server, and each customer brings an exponentially distributed amount of work with rate $\mu$, independently of everything else.
This, however, is not a classical infinite-server queue, as the customers interact in the following way: whenever a customer at server i is completely served, it, along with all other customers at servers $i+1,i+2,i+3,...,$ leave the system.

If we let $Q(t)$ denote the number of customers in the system at time $t, t ≥ 0$, then $\{Q(t); t ≥ 0\}$ is a CTMC. What would be the rate this chain goes from state 3 to state 2, 1 and 0? My thought was that these rates are $\mu$, $2\mu$ and $3\mu$ respectively, since to go from 3 to 2 we need the last customer to finish first; from 3 to 1 we need the minimum of the next to the last customer to finish and from 3 to 0 we need the the first customer to finish. However, the solution I have says that these rates should be 0,0, $3\mu$ respectively. I'm hoping somebody will be able to explain to me why is this right?

Comment: If we are in state 3 then there are 4 independent exponentials racing against each other (one exp $\lambda$ and three exp $\mu$), exactly one of these 4 will be the first to complete, and so as I understand the system it would be $q_{34} = \lambda, q_{32} = \mu, q_{31}=\mu, q_{30} = \mu$.

Comment: @Michael In order for one of the 4 to be first to complete, it must be the minimum of the 4. So, we'd need to use somehow, the fact that the min of exponential variables is still exponential with the rate = the sum of all rates.

Comment: Same principle for a basic M/M/1 queue: in state 3 we have two racing exponentials so $q_{34}=\lambda$ and $q_{32}=\mu$. It is true that the winning time is exponential with the sum of rates of all outgoing arrows, so $\lambda+\mu$, but so what?